# In ASP.NET MVC how do you allow a controller to be accessed anonymously (without login)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in this MVC app made by others, every page requires you to login first. How do I set one of my controllers to work without having to be logged in? At first I thought this was due to the master page but when I removed the master page it still redirects to login when they first browse to the controller action. Is this set in the web.config still like traditional asp.net webforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the action method that you want to access remove the attribute

```
[Authorize]
```

that is before it.

Comment: You can also apply this to the Controller left rather than a single Action method.

Comment: I think I am using a custom base class for the controllers that my fellow devs made, do you think it could be in there?